# As Access Traverses A Recordset Does It Slow Down As The Index Increases, And Why?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2003, recordset

I have the following scenario and was wondering if it was effecting the speed of execution

- Select statement pulls 100,000 rows and puts it into a DAO.recordset
- The recordset manipulates, we'll say, 5000 of those records at a time doing the following

  - Run some expensive string manipulation and functions (already optimized)
  - Insert results into a table
  - Repeat until recordset is empty
- Update original table with results

As the recordset gets further into the index it seems as if the program slows down.

I know that Access doesn't pull all of the records into memory at one time, so why is this going so slowly?

Comment: Try benchmarking the individual parts of your code with the MicroTimer function found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730921.aspx#Office2007excelPerf_MakingWorkbooksCalculateFaster), just scroll down a bit to the piece of code.  You can use that to determine where your code is spending most of its time: moving through the recordset, loading the data out of the records into your variables, performing the string manipulation or saving the result to the new table.

Comment: The timing works pretty well moving through those processes in about 20 seconds per set of 5000 . Although as it approaches the upper limit of a large recordset that time increases to minutes in between sets of 5000. The Micro Timer, although a good idea, won't do much good here as I have a few things watching the time already.

Comment: What I mean is, WHICH PART of your code is taking longer?  The String manipulations?  Recordset.MoveNext? Recordset.Update? Odds are, the slowdown is due to one particular part of your code and it may be possible to keep it from happening.  A coworker and I benchmarked some code that was processing a few hundred thousand records.  We found that a few key parts of the code were causing a bottleneck.  We optimized those sections and a process that used to take 8 days suddenly took 8 hours.  If you can figure out WHICH PART is growing in time each iteration, that will help answer the question.

Comment: @Blackhawk, ah, understood now. When I get the chance I'll change how my current timers work and put the results here. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up selecting a small set of data from my recordset using the following logic

```
Base Query
    If not end or beginning of recordset  then
        Do while Not end of recordset
        DO CODE
        If end of recordset rerun Base Query
    end loop
```

What this does is pull small sets of data into memory, reducing overhead when traversing your data set. This does require quite a few more hits to the DB, but reduces time significantly, especially if the query has/had been optimized.